# Ration your integers and feed the people

Tags: code-challenge

It is wartime, and rationing is taking place in certain regions of your country. Your cities' region is one such region. The city chooses to give everyone the same amount, but in reality, larger people need more food. Chances are, a 200lb man is going to be eating more than that 7lb baby over there. The city, realizing that some people need more food, hires you, their best computer programmer, to solve the issue. They want you to write a program that will divvy up the food appropriately.

Being a smart programmer, you have developed a formula that gives an approximation of how much someone will eat based on their weight.

`EAT = (WEIGHT - 1) / 20 + 1`

For example, a 124 pound man will eat 7.125 units of food. Knowing that the food is served in packages of 1, and it would be irrational to cut them up, you can round the food units.

Each day, every person eats that many food units. If somebody goes for five days straight with less than that much food per day, they die of starvation.

You will receive population data in this form: `Population*Weight`, so if you receive `700*180`, you know that their are 700 180lb men in the city. Your city has 100,000 units of food stored away.

For every day your city goes without anyone dying, you get one point. Whoever has the most points wins. Make sure you output how many days your city lasted before someone died.

Here is the input:

`1000x90
2500x80
3000x150
2500x200`

Edit: So, the rule "For every day your city goes without anyone dying, you get one point" was terribly abused. Rule change here: if *anybody* dies, then game over. No more counting.

Comment: I like it. Those who habitually eat too much (and therefore are obese) get to carry on eating too much. This is exactly the way bureaucracy works (especially with annual budgets.) +1.

Comment: `If somebody goes for five days straight with less than that much food, they die of starvation.` This means if somebody goes for 5 days straight with less than the portion of food that person needs for 1 day, then they die of starvation?

Comment: This is really neat. Just a few things: is the separator `x` or `*` or up to us? Any restrictions on the kind of input? Does it have to be from stdin or could it be a function argument? Does it have to be a `\n` delimited string or could it be an array of strings? What rounding should we use? And what's the output? Just the number of days? Or instructions on how to distribute food each day? Also some simple solved test cases might be useful...

Comment: It's generally a good idea to run challenges through the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/proposed-question-sandbox-mark-xi) before posting to clarify such things.

Comment: You've told us what form the input will take, but not what we should output.

Comment: Also, if I feed each person the required amount every fifth day and don't feed them at all for the other 4 days no one will die, whereas if I'm 0.0001 unit below the required amount for 5 days in a row they die. Seems a bit unfair?

Comment: Thinking about it, isn't the solution actually quite trivial? To keep everyone alive for the first five days, I need to feed each person their required ration on day 5, which costs me `70550` units assuming "normal" rounding. The next 4 days no one will starve, but on day 10 I don't have another `70550` units to avoid someone dying. So 9 days is the maximum. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @m.buettner I correct you in the form of my answer. ;)

Comment: @Doorknob I agree that "For every day your city goes without anyone dying, you get one point. Whoever has the most points wins." could be interpreted as you did it. But "Make sure you output how many days your city lasted before someone died." really seems to mean that the OP was getting at how long you can go without anyone dying at all. In any case that doesn't change that the solution is quite trivial and not subject to any interesting optimisation.

Comment: @m.buettner Okay, now I output how many days I lasted before someone died. The OP never mentioned anything about that affecting the score. :D

Comment: Rounding definitely needs to be defined.

Comment: Rounding eat up gives 70,000 units per day. Rounding down gives 66,500 units per day. Doesn't seem like one could make the bulk of the city survive for more than a few days

Comment: Aww, question got closed just as I wanted to post this answer:

# `bc` / bash
It's a nice challenge, but I had the same idea as @m.buettner had and was going to post a comment along the lines of "you don't need a program for this, a mere calculator is enough". Then I realised, that there is a nice calculator in Unix: `bc`:

    `scale=3;
    define eat(w) { return (w - 1) / 20 + 1; }
    needperfivedays = (1000*eat(90) + 2500*eat(80) + 3000*eat(150) + 2500*eat(200));
    5 * (1 + 100000 / needperfivedays );`

Comment: Sad. This question has potential too. If only some more detail on how/when people die.

Comment: Ass. Happened again to me. [Online Python version](http://glot.io/python/f068ced2a19b17384444b3d6f86b9c38) lasted 10 days. Could probably get more by tweaking the algorithm. Another question i could not answer at time. D:

Comment: All those who closed: pleas see the bottom of the post.

Comment: @joeelectricity please re-read my comments. Even with this last line there remain several things to clarify and in any case, this problem does seem to present any actual challenge which would inspire interesting (or even competing) answers. That's why I can only (again) suggest, you post this in the sandbox and try to refine the challenge with the help of the community.

Answer (score 12):

## Ruby, 100003 days/points (~274 years), 5 days before *someone* dies

> For every day your city goes without anyone dying, you get one point.

I shall abuse this rule as much as possible!

> Make sure you output how many days your city lasted before someone died.

Ok, I did. You didn't say anything about that affecting your score.

```
#input = STDIN.read
input = "1000x90
2500x80
3000x150
2500x200" # temporary debugging tool

food = 100000

input = input.split.map{|x| x.split('x').map &:to_i }
onlyPersonToFeedWeight = input.sort_by! {|a|
  a[1] # weight of person
}.first[1] # find the lightest weighing person
foodForOnePerson =  ((onlyPersonToFeedWeight - 1) / 20.0 + 1).ceil # EAT = (WEIGHT - 1) / 20 + 1

# you can see where this is going

daysNobodyDied = 0
daysSomeoneDied = 0

# first kill off all these overweight people
daysNobodyDied += 4
food -= foodForOnePerson
daysSomeoneDied += 1 # it's only all but one person in the city, don't worry

# I have a good feeling about this now
# ... I'm evil

loop {
  daysNobodyDied += 4
  food -= foodForOnePerson
  if food >= 0
    daysNobodyDied += 1
  else
    daysSomeoneDied += 1
    break
  end
}

puts "Survived for #{daysNobodyDied} days"
puts "There were #{daysSomeoneDied} days in which someone died"
puts "The first person died on day 5"
```

Output:

```
Survived for 100003 days
There were 2 days in which someone died
The first person died on day 5
```

I suggest you read the comments in the code first; they're quite amusing. ;) (Code is intentionally verbose.)

The strategy is simple:

- On the first five days, only feed the lightest person (on the fifth day). Then everyone else dies so you don't have to worry about them.
- Continue to starve this poor man with no friends or family by only feeding him once every five days until you run out of food.
- The man will probably die before you run out of food since it will now last 274 years.

Does this make me evil or something?

Oh, and by the way, if he was lying down the whole time, [he'd have a better than even chance that a bird would poop in his mouth](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100003%20days). (Assuming the birds didn't starve.) Thanks for the... interesting fact, @Synthetica :-P

Comment: I thought the output was "...how many days your city lasted before *someone* died", not until *everyone* died.

Comment: @Geobits "For every day your city goes without anyone dying, you get one point."

Comment: I suppose the OP needs to clarify the point, since it can be interpreted both ways.

Comment: I think the obvious interpretation is at the point of the first death the game is over. You want `city` to be defined? `day`? `dying`? Fun interpretation. I feel that there are large quantities of protein which become available, so with males, females, and sufficient arrangement of deaths for consumption, there may be a way to get to 274 year (and longer) with population remaining. Another question, perhaps...

Comment: On mature reflection, your answer is growing on me. Upvoted even. Realised the question as it stands is not about any actual programming, but just coding a program correctly. So why not? Let me find my copy of Soylent Green and see if I can get some ideas...

Comment: BTW, is this guy doing anything beside just hanging around? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100003%20days I didn't know the guys at Wolfram|Alpha red whatif-XKCD ;).

Comment: Following your argument you can put the score to infinity. The poster didn't specify that you should stop counting when the last one died. That's even more ridiculous and shows that it is a non-answer.

Comment: Please see my edit; I hadn't realized the loophole there ;). Under the new meanie rules, you only got 5 points.

Comment: Under this interpretation you have infinite days. Even after the last person dies, there's many days where no one dies.